# A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'KeySpec'

Tags: powershell, ssl, self-signed-certificate

I am trying to create SSL and getting following error: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'KeySpec'.

```
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" -DnsName "sampleapp.test.com" -KeySpec Signature -FriendlyName "saml app"
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: The KeySpec option was only introduced in later versions of the commandlet.
See [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps) for Windows 10 and server 2016
versus [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=winserver2012-ps) for Windows 2012 server.
to see the differences.